# Reading specific bytes of data from a large text file... quickly

Tags: file-io, format, save, loading, game-engine

For argument's sake, let's say you have a single, enormous file to hold your map save data. The game that comes to mind as a great example is Terraria. They save all MapWidth*MapHeight tile data within a single map file (Horrible idea, really) but they can render only what is visible within the camera (And some outer-lying tiles for smoothness sake) based on the camera position.

So my question is, "How can they search through all of that data in real time starting at the camera position?"

That would entail reading through potentially millions of tile data just to get to the screen coordinates. I understand you could skip bytes of data based on the x/y coordinates if the tile data was consistent (This is all I can find in my week or so of searching), but that is where my problem lies. The tile data is dynamic. If one tile is empty, the data beyond "isValid" is nonexistent. So that is less bytes to search through. If a tile has water, multiple states, a background, etc... it contains all the data and is the largest in terms of bytes. So it is not constant at all. In that case we cannot just skip X amount of bytes as it changes (Constantly as tiles are modified).

My current solutions are: Read it line by line (Ugh), use chunk files, or ensure fixed line sizes (Padding? Data wasted... Ugh).

I know chunks would be the best option, but being able to reach that deep into text files quickly would still be a nice thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chunk-based data, you need a chunk-based reader, simple as that.

Additionally, if you're particularly interested only in certain parts of the data and you can process it first, is to build a second file/list that stores the offsets to the start of every object in the first file.

In that case, whenever you need to reference an object, you look up the offset first and then do a straight jump to it in your original file. It still requires you to read through the whole file at-least once.